# Blender 2.8 Wireframe and Subdivision overlaps when seaming

Tags: uv, subdivision-surface

I'm seaming the edges for UVing. It's a mesh with subdivision modifier in effect(not applied).
The wireframe mesh disappears inside the subdivision as expected, but this blocks my view from actually seeing the edge to select it properly.

Question: Are there any settings to help me out and prevent this visual impairment, or do I just go with it?

Is there some other method I don't know about?

XRAY is currently off but it makes a horrible confusion when activated(shows all subdivision edges), so I don't see it as the solution.

It would be great if the entire low poly mesh edges were to show significantly in XRAY mode, right now the XRAY shows me original mesh and subdivision result overlapping, creating a guess who game with sticks.

Do viewport gizmos have such a setting? I wasn't able to see any.

[image: Seam disappears inside when subsurfed]

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't hide the subdivision modifier for the edit mode and then use x-ray?

Comment: That's how I worked around it I think.